# javascript worker takes up ram after being terminated and removed

Tags: javascript, web-worker

i've been playing around with workers and wanted to know what exactly i need to do to get entirely rid of one. up until recently i figured terminating them and removing the references to them would do it, but i recently did a test on it and found out there is still ram being used unnecessarily.

i used the following code to create and remove some workers (granted, i needed to create 100000 of them to get a noticable result, but just the existence of a potential ram leak bothers me). after creating and removing them, they used up 2000mb of ram, which quickly dropped to 300mb after some garbage collecting has been done.

does anyone know what those 300mb are still being used for and how i can get rid of them?
my code:

```js
function inlineWorker (fun) {
    if (fun !== undefined && typeof fun === "function") {
        const burl = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([
            "(" + fun.toString() + ")()"
        ], { type: 'application/javascript' }));

        const worker = new Worker(burl);

        URL.revokeObjectURL(burl);

        return worker;
    } else {
        throw "wrong argument";
    }
}

let workers = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    workers.push(inlineWorker(function () {
        this.addEventListener("message", function (data) {
            this.postMessage(data.data);
        });
    }));
    workers[workers.length - 1].addEventListener("message", function (data) {
        console.log(data.data);
    });
    workers[workers.length - 1].terminate();
}

workers = undefined;

window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
    console.log(workers);
});
```

Comment: Where did you get the measurements from? On which browser do you see this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Where is the 300Mb? Well in general garbage collector has little motivation to clean already allocated memory within some bounds, since it can reuse the memory later for other objects and data. Don't expect the memory used to exactly match what variables are still in use.

However in your case, there may be a thing that even advanced JS devs often forget: listeners are capture scopes and they might not be deleted along with the object that created them. Try removing all listeners before clearing the array. Also try to use single instance of `fun`. Although the browser should be able to figure it out, I'm not sure if it does.

Comment: Regarding the events, since they are either only internal to the Worker scope, or only attached to the Worker object, I doubt there could be any leak here. In the first case, the event-loop where they've been registered is simply destroyed at `terminate()` for the other one, their EventTarget is unreferenced at `workers = undefined`.

Comment: @Kaiido Yeah, but the functions still capture the scope in which they were created. I'm not 100% sure, but I think in some cases that may keep them alive.